# Push notifications from web server to desktop app in python

Tags: python, django, comet, long-polling

I have a service with users (in django) and desktop client for this srevice (on wxpython). I need to send notifications from server to desktop app for specific user.

What I can use for it?

Thank you!

Comment: Could be `django socket.io` [git site](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know wxPython, but if you want to use long-polling, comet or another technique based on HTTP protocol, then you need to write HTTP client or use any network framework.

For example [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Make connection to your django server and send data through TCP transport using HTTP protocol.